# NXT - What is the difference between an Asset and a Currency?

Tags: currencies, nxt, decentralized-assets

Reading the NXT website, it talks about an [Asset Exchange](http://nxt.org/about/asset-exchange/) and a [Monetary System](http://nxt.org/about/monetary-system/). First seems to be regarding assets, while the second article one is talking about currencies. Is there any difference between those two, is one a subset of the other, or are they all the same?

Comment: In some places, they seem to be drawing the distinction that a currency is a means for measuring the magnitude of assets while an asset has to have a specific location, issuer, or backer. But in other places, they seem to use the terms interchangeably. (Dollars are a *currency*. If I have a 10 dollars bill in my pocket, that's an *asset*, whose magnitude is 10 dollars. Currencies are how you measure how much of an asset you have.)

Comment: I'll try to login tonight and more throughly explain.  Functionally they are very different.  Assets are like simple stocks.  MS currencies have a whole slew of properties thaf allow you to customize your own token/currency. You could create a currency where you can create/destroy units (for usecases like arcades) or you could create dynamic scenarios where users can create coins when certain conditions are met.  Many of the new MS currencies are full-fledged PoW coins.  No code necessary.  Spec the currency, pay the Nxt fee and you've created your own custom cryptocurrency.